# Could a person be indefinitely detained without trial by being briefly released every 24 hours?

Tags: false-arrest

As I understand it the police must charge someone with a crime within 24 hours of arresting them. Suppose the police wanted someone put away but didn't want to go through the trouble of convicting them. Could they arrest them, set a 24-hour timer, then when that timer expires let the person outside the jail for 5 seconds before arresting them again? Is there any jurisdiction with rules to prevent this tactic?

Comment: 24 hours isn't a rule everywhere: In Japan, Police can hold you 28 days, and then just add another charge to keep you another 28 days and again and again.

Comment: If my client was only "free" for five seconds (or other such minimal amount) I would argue that they were never really free.

Comment: Related question: [Explanation of "habeas corpus"](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/21170/10281)

Answer (score 2):

Rules on such things vary significantly by jurisdiction. To get a specific and accurate answer, please specify the jurisdiction of interest. Some jurisdictions have rules or laws forbidding the sort of maneuver described in the question, others do not.